# each value of array is a object subproperty of the previous array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

so I have an array `['banana', 'apple', 'grape']`

how can I transform into the object below?

```
{
   banana: {
       apple: {
           grape: { }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) to recursively build the result object:

```js
const data = ['banana', 'apple', 'grape'];

const result = data.reduceRight((a, v) => ({ [v]: a }), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice use of `reduceRight`, it took me sometime to understand it, an explanation around, how we are always getting reference of outer object will be really helpful. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop over given value and keep track of previously added object

```js
let arr = ['banana', 'apple', 'grape']


function createObj(arr) {
  let obj = {}
  let temp = obj

  for (let key of arr) {
    temp[key] = {}
    temp = temp[key]
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(createObj(arr))
```